# How to install c++ via yum command without using "Development Tools" group?

Tags: c++, yum

I want to run c++ on my centos machine. My Google searches says that run `yum group install "Development Tools"` command but this downloads other packages too like bison,perl,automake, etc which is not required for my use-case and only increases my docker container size. Can someone suggest the necessary packages required to run c++ ?
TIA

Answer (score 2):

The only necessary tool to "run" C++ (aka build C++) is a compiler:

```sh
sudo yum install gcc
echo "#include <iostream>" > main.cpp
echo "int main(){ std::cout << \"Hello World\" << std::endl; }" >> main.cpp  
gcc main.cpp -o test -lstdc++ 
./test
```

Comment: This might require `g++` explicitly. Sometimes that's separate. Depends on the packager.

Comment: I tried on my centos to get `g++` with "not found" result. The above script worked, but my machine is not a clean install. The OP might need to try.

Comment: Might be the case. I've had to ask for it before on Fedora, which is why I mention it, as it's in the same family as CentOS (RedHat).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

This will install default gcc version supplied by your distro.
If you are on RHEL 7 and/or CentOS 7, the default gcc version is quite outdated (4.8.5), so you may want to install "devtoolset-N", which provide newer GCC versions, via Software Collections, for example look at [this one](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/). In there, in my experience, installing the devtoolset-N package will install the whole buch of stuff, similar to what `groupinstall "Development Tools"` does, so for Docker container it is good enough to only install `devtoolset-N-toolchain`. I also once needed `devtoolset-N-libatomic-devel`.